# User details update and secure controller

Tags: php, laravel-5

I have started to learn Laravel 5.* and currently I'm working on some basic admin panel. Create users/delte/edit etc.

I've got this for update user details

```
public function update( UserRequest $request){

    $user = User::find( $request['id'] );

    $hasuser = User::where('email','=',$request['email'])->where('id','!=',$request['id'])->first();
    if($hasuser){
        $request->session()->flash('alert-error','User with given email address already exist. Plese try with another email address!!.');
        return redirect()->route('admin.users'); 
    }

    $user->name =  $request['name'];
    $user->email =  $request['email'];
    $user->phone =  $request['phone'];
    $user->role =  $request['role'];

    if(!empty($request['password'])){
        $password = bcrypt($request['password']);
        $user->password = $password;    
    }

    if($user->save())
        $request->session()->flash('alert-success','User updated successfully.');
    else
        $request->session()->flash('alert-error','Can not update User now. Please try again!!.');

    return redirect()->route('admin.users');
}
```

What I'm not sure is the query

```
$hasuser = User::where('email','=',$request['email'])->where('id','!=',$request['id'])->first();
```

Is it good from security and sql injection point of view this variable there i.e. `$request['email']`, `$request['id']`

If not can you show me what is a good approach here?

Answer (score 1):

Laravel's Eloquent ORM uses PDO binding to avoid SQL injection, but that's not to say it's not good practice to validate user input before you do anything with it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you tell me is there something special in Laravel validation user input? I mean some special function... can you show me example?

Comment: For example something like this: `!filter_var($request['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`?

Comment: you can also ask for old password for update with new password and check it on update

Comment: What about email filter and validation